# How to calculate subnet mask including, network address, gateway, broadcast address and host range?

Tags: routing, subnet, broadcast

You are defining network boundaries within a /24 network of 172.30.20.0/24. Please  complete the segmentation of the /24 to account for multiple smaller networks of 115,   50, 28, 12, and 5 hosts. Include the subnet mask, network address, gateway, broadcast   address and host range of each segment.

Comment: No, but thank you for showing me that. I think I am supposed to provide the subnet mask, network address, gateway, broadcast address and host range of those networks that have 115, 50, 28, 12, and 5 hosts

Comment: Education or homework questions are off topic here, but the answer is in the question I showed you.